# How do I reference a resource in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, embedded-resource

I need to read a file in my code.  It physically resides here:

```
C:\eclipseWorkspace\ProjectA\src\com\company\somePackage\MyFile.txt
```

I've put it in a source package so that when I create a runnable jar file (Export->Runnable JAR file) it gets included in the jar.  Originally I had it in the project root (and also tried a normal sub folder), but the export wasn't including it in the jar.

If in my code I do:

```
File myFile = new File("com\\company\\somePackage\\MyFile.txt");
```

the jar file correctly locates the file, but running locally (Run As->Java Main application) throws a file not found exception because it expects it to be:

```
File myFile = new File("src\\com\\company\\somePackage\\MyFile.txt");
```

But this fails in my jar file.  So my question is, how do I make this concept work for both running locally and in my jar file?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) or [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). The main difference between the two is that the `ClassLoader` version always uses an "absolute" path (within the jar file or whatever) whereas the `Class` version is relative to the class itself, unless you prefix the path with /.

So if you have a class `com.company.somePackage.SomeClass` and `com.company.other.AnyClass` (within the same classloader as the resource) you could use:

```
SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("MyFile.txt")
```

or

```
AnyClass.class.getClassLoader()
              .getResourceAsStream("com/company/somePackage/MyFile.txt");
```

or

```
AnyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/company/somePackage/MyFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have placed i file in a jar file, it only worked if and only if I used

```
...getResourceAsStream("com/company/somePackage/MyFile.txt")
```

If I used a File object it never worked. I got also the FileNotFound exception. Now, I stay with the InputStream object.