# Cannot load image getting null-pointer exception

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to add an image from the "photographs" folder into a list. The list has been initialized and the relative path of the photo is correct. PhotographicGame is the name of the class where this method is written. I keep on getting a null pointer exception when the method tries to "add" the image to the list. 
HELP!!

I have another case in which I used this exact method and had no problems!

```
    private List<Image> populateList()
    {
        photoList.add(new Image(PhotographicGame.class.getResourceAsStream("photographs/faces/face1.jpg"), 200, 400, true, true));
        return photoList;
    }
```

**UPDATED:**
Once i try to perform the above mentioned action im getting an error like:

```
    Mar 11, 2016 2:10:53 AM brainbright.gui.gameselect.GameSelectController startGame
SEVERE: null
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/D/Documents/3/Industrial/new/BrainBright-master/dist/run285479268/BrainBright.jar!/brainbright/gui/facenamehouse/FaceNameHouse.fxml:85

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at brainbright.gui.gameselect.GameSelectController.startGame(GameSelectController.java:362)
    at brainbright.gui.gameselect.GameSelectController.handleStartAction(GameSelectController.java:304)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.layout.HBox field brainbright.gui.facenamehouse.FaceNameHouseController.faceContainer to javafx.scene.layout.VBox
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 67 more
```

Comment: What does the NullPointerException say?  Does it say: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null`?  If so, then the jpg was not found, if not then `photoList` was not initialized and is null.

Comment: Good point. Would be worth factoring this out into smaller lines. Get your stream first, then create your image. Then add it to your list. And see where it's failing. It's either an issue with your path, or the resource is not being found at the path, I think.

Comment: I did actually break it down, and the error I keep getting is a simple null pointer exception at the "photoList.add(image);" line

Comment: I just ran a test and it worked fine for me, using the same path you've defined above, even with a package structure for my calling class. So, either your image isn't loading as a stream, or your photoList has not been initialized. Check which is null and correct accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I just want to make sure I understand correctly...

By initialization you mean declaring it. as so:
private List<Image> photoList;

If this is what you mean, then yes I have done this step.

Comment: Also, I initialized it to null - photoList = null; - before trying to add the image to it

Comment: No, you need to initialize it e.g. List<Image> photoList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: That is to instantiate, and it gives me an error when I do that, saying "List is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated"

Comment: You can't instantiate List. It needs to be a subclass of List, such as ArrayList. See my comment above.

Comment: @dailyadd I recommend you pick up a [Java fundamentals book](http://www.amazon.com/Core-Volume-I-Fundamentals-Edition-Series/dp/0134177304/ref=zg_bs_3608_11) and study it, as well as the [basic Java trails](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: @jewelsea this is still a hint not a solution

Comment: @ManoDestra i just tried that and it did not work, seems that it might be a minor problem in another part of the code which affects this list

Comment: Yep. You need to instantiate the list before you can use it. And you should ensure that nothing else is setting it back to null.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your string isn't closed above. I assume that it is in your actual code.

Check that the image is on your classpath, in that location. I had a similar issue as I was forgetting to deploy my images to my compiled classes folder, ready for building into a JAR.

You may have to add a forward slash at the front, to reference it from the root of your classpath. Otherwise, it may be trying to locate that relative path from the calling class. See here: [How do I reference a resource in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727994/how-do-i-reference-a-resource-in-java)

I tried the following test:

```
package test.game;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Image image = new Image(MainApp.class.getResourceAsStream("photos/faces/Sunset01.jpg"), 400, 200, true, true);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);

        Group group = new Group(imageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 800, 600);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Main App");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

I put my MainApp.java file in test/game and my Sunset01.jpg in test/game/photos/faces. And it worked fine. So, it must be an issue with your image loading, being copied to your output directory, your runtime classpath or your photoList being initialized (e.g. `List<Image> photoList = new ArrayList<>();`).

Comment: I tried adding the forward slash but it didnt solve the problem.

Comment: Can you add your project structure to the question? Check that the image is actually on the classpath that you're referencing.

Comment: yes, im 100% sure that it is on that class path, the folder being accessed is in the same folder of the PhotographicGame class.

Comment: Make sure it's being copied to your output directory though. And try referencing it from the root of the classpath: `/fully/qualified/path/to/PhotographicGame/photographs/faces/face1.jpg`. If that's not working, then it's probably not being copied over to your output directory.